# Getting updated values of bitcoin through api using javascript

Tags: javascript, api, bitcoin

I am getting bitcoin data from API. I am loading values after every one second. But the values in API changes almost after 3 minutes. I want to show API changes values after one second like preev.com. I have uploaded the javascript code below. Please help me.

```
function fetchdata(){
 fetch("https://index-api.bitcoin.com/api/v0/price/usd")
   .then((res) => res.json())
   .then((data) => {
     console.log(data['price']);
   })
}
setInterval(fetchdata, 1000);
```

Comment: I guess if API refreshes data after three minutes, and you want it to refresh every second, then you need a different API.

Answer (score -1):

To reload the data every second, you can basically do an infinite cycle that fetches data and then sleeps for a second. This piece of code must be in an asyncronous function.

```
async function UpdateBitcoinDataThread() {
  while(true){
  //fetch data method call
  await fetchData();

  //sleep
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
  }
}
```

Make sure to not await this function or the main thread will await forever.